# Add field in JSON not in interface Vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex

i'm using vue/cli 4.3.1
vue: 2.6.11

i have array in json and i want add value in it depending on value in another field.
like:

```
"rules":[{"id":1,"name":"new rule","patient":[],"code":[1],"to_code":[1]}]
```

if code array contain index of code value ==50 
then to_code is contain index of to code value 100
otherwise to_code is empty in this rule
code:

```
 {"code":[{"id":1,"name":"New Item","values":[{"id":1,"code":"50"}]}]
to_code:
"to_code":[{"id":1,"name":"To code 100","values":100}
```

the data in JSON collect in this function :

```
  saveData() {

      let params = {
        data: {
          code: this.codeList,

          to_code: this.toCodeList

          rules: this.pacList
        }
      };
```

the state in vuex:

```
   toCodeList: state => state.to_codes,
codeList: state => state.codes,
```

save Vue Store(Local) in this function:

```
  saveRule() {

      if (this.ruleItem.id > 0) {
        console.log(this.ruleItem);
      } else {
        let newId = 1;
        if (this.pacList.length > 0) {
          newId =
            Math.max.apply(
              Math,
              this.pacList.map(function(o) {
                return o.id;
              })
            ) + 1;
        }

        this.ruleItem.id = newId;

        this.pacList.push(this.ruleItem);
      }
```

create new rule function:

```
   createRule() {

      this.ruleItem = { ...this.emptyRule };
```

empty rule:

```
 emptyRule: {
      id: 0,
      name: "new rule",
      code: [],
      to_code:[]
}
```

what i tried to do in saveRule function :

```
      var parsedobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.codeList));

      parsedobj.forEach(arrayItem => {
        var x = arrayItem.values;
        for (let item = 0; item < x.length; item++) {
          const element = x[item].id;
          const codenumber = x[item].code;
          if (codenumber == 50 || codenumber == 200) {
            let correctID = x[item].id;

            var parsepaclist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.pacList));

            parsepaclist.forEach(pacitem => {
              for (let index = 0; index < parsepaclist.length; index++) {
                const IDofpaclist = parsepaclist[index].id;
                const Itemofpaclist = parsepaclist[index];

                var numberofDestPort = pacitem.code;

                if (correctID == Itemofpaclist.code) {
                  if (codenumber == 50) {
                    let newtocode = {
                      id: 1,
                      name: "To code 100",
                      values: 100,
                      active: false
                    };
                    this.tocodelist.push(newtocode);

                    Itemofpaclist.to_code.push(1);

                    if (Itemofpaclist.id == this.ruleItem.id) {
                      this.ruleItem.to_code = Itemofpaclist.to_code;
                    }
                  } else if (codenumber == 200) {
                    let newtocode = {
                      id: 2,
                      name: "To Code 300",
                      values: 300,
                      active: false
                    };
                    this.tocodelist.push(newtocode);

                    Itemofpaclist.to_code.push(2);
                    if (Itemofpaclist.id == this.ruleItem.id) {
                      this.ruleItem.to_code = Itemofpaclist.to_code;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
```

The problem is when i add code 50
toCode object in Json don't  contain index of  to code value 100
or in code 200 toCode object in Json don't  contain index of  to code value 300

Comment: You have provided a lot of info but still failed to explain what your issue actually is. What do you want to achieve ? And what have you tried but did not work ?

Comment: i edited the question by what i tried to do

Comment: I read your inquiry many times but I didn't understand what did you mean .. would you explain this "The problem is when i add code 50 toCode object in Json don't contain index of to code value 100 or in code 200 toCode object in Json don't contain index of to code value 300" ?

Comment: I also see you defined `codenumber` and used it `if (codenumber == 50 || codenumber == 200) {` then you used `portnumber` in the sub conditions `if (portnumber == 50) {` and `} else if (portnumber == 200) {` this might be the wrong with your code!

Comment: i mean by that i want to_code object in Json to contain number of index of value 100  in to_code object when the "code" object contain index of value 50 in code object

Comment: thanks for your comment i edited the question

Comment: It might be a caveat issue, I can help with debugging this issue .. can you share your code on Github ? if you are not able to, then let's hangout and share your screen so I can help .. Skype: hsniper7

Answer (score 0):

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
      code: {},
      to_code: {},
      rule: {}
    },
    created: function () {
      this.code = Object.assign({"code":[{"id":1,"name":"New Item","values":[{"id":1,"code":"50"}]}]})
      this.to_code = Object.assign({"to_code":[{"id":1,"name":"To code 100","values":100}]})
      // this.rule = 

      for (var i = this.code.code.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var code = this.code.code[i]['values']

        for (var k = code.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {

          if (code[k]['code'] == 50) {

            for (var j = this.to_code.to_code.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

              var to_code = this.to_code.to_code[j]['values']

              if (to_code == 100) {
                this.rule = Object.assign({"rules":[{"id":1,"name":"new rule","patient":[],"code": this.code.code[i],"to_code":this.to_code.to_code[j]}]})
              }
            }

          } else {
            this.rule = Object.assign({"rules":[{"id":1,"name":"new rule","patient":[],"code": this.code.code[i],"to_code":[]}]})
          }

        };

      };
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.rule))
    }
  })
```

> You can set your requirement and code in this coding structure.
>   Thanks.